# How to limit method parameter of enum type to certain literal?

Tags: java, enums

I would like to limit enum literal of particular type in parameter.

For example,

```java
enum SomeEnum { A, B, C}
class SomeClass {
    public void doSomething(SomeEnum someEnum) { <--- Here I want to only accept A and C. 
    }
}
```

so as caller is typing the code,

```java
SomeClass someclass = new SomeClass();
someclass.doSomething(); <------- java assist would say only A and C goes in here
```

Comment: Why is `B` unacceptable?  Do you want a compiler error or a runtime error?

Comment: You could do runtime check inside the method.. There is no standard way to do it at the compile time

Comment: @rgettman Let's assume B is unacceptable for some reason. Compile time error would be better.

Comment: You can't. But it's hard to offer an alternative without a better understanding of the scenario.

Comment: I'm not at all a fan of enums with methods, but you could move `doSomething()` *into* `A` and `C` and not `B`, with suitable parameter changes, so it would be impossible to call `B.doSomething()`.

Answer (score -1):

Add an enum set of values to the some class either hard coded or in a constructor.